# calling apex method in Ajax on click of input tag

Tags: ajax

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="showDuplicates">

    <apex:form >
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css"
              rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                modal: true,
                autoOpen: false,
                title: "jQuery Dialog",
                width: 300,
                height: 150
            });
            $("#btnShow").click(function () {
                console.log()
                $('#dialog').dialog('open');
            });
        });
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        var __sfdcSessionId = '{!GETSESSIONID()}';
        </script>

        <script src="../../soap/ajax/38.0/connection.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../../soap/ajax/10.0/apex.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>        
        function dde(){
            var myvar = sforce.apex.execute("showDuplicates","create");
            window.alert(myvar);
        }
        </script>

        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:inputText value="{!name}" label="Name"/>
                <apex:inputText value="{!billincity}" label="BillingCity"/>
                <apex:inputText value="{!billingcode}" label="BillingPostalCode"/>
                <input type="Text" id="btnShow" value="{!phone}" onclick="dde();"/>
                <div id="dialog" style="display: none" align = "center" >
                    This is a jQuery Dialog. 
                </div>

            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

calling apex method through Ajax in Vf Page,syntax seems correct but my calss is not called,

Answer (score 0):

You always need to supply three parameters to sforce.apex.execute, even if there's no parameters to pass to the function. You do this by using an empty object (`{}`).

```
sforce.apex.execute('showDuplicates','create',{});
```

This is mentioned [in the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_and_ajax.htm):

> To call a webService method with no parameters, use {} as the third parameter for sforce.apex.execute. For example, to call the following Apex class:
>
> ```
> global class myClass{ 
>     webService static String getContextUserName() {
>         return UserInfo.getFirstName();
>     }
> }
> ```